# RewriteCond fails on existing file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, my .htaccess file starts with:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

And I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
or
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
or
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

But RewriteRule never executes.

.htaccess file placed in the / of site.

Comment: Fails on existing file... What do you think -f does?

Comment: RewriteCond somepath -f goes to next cond or rule if there is a file on somepath. -f means file